# x86 assembly macro for invoking a function (with arguments)

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, macros

I'm trying to write a macro (in x86 assembly) that invokes a function with arguments. Variable number of arguments, that is. The functions is the first macro argument, and function arguments are 2nd-nth macro arguments.

In other words, `INVOKE foo, 1, 2, 3` should expand to (**stdcall** convention):

> *push arguments*
>
> *call foo*
>
> *clean stack*

I figured `irp` should do the trick, and wrote the following:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.arch i386

.data
    if: .asciz "%i\n"
.text

.macro INVOKE func, argList
    .irp arg,<argList>
    push \arg
    .endr
    call \func
    .irp arg,<argList>
    add esp, 4
    .endr
.endm
```

And for the test:

```
.globl  main
    .extern foo
main:
    INVOKE foo, 1, 5, 10, 15
    
    push eax
    push offset if
    call printf
    
    ret
.end
```

With a separate c file with `foo`:

```
int foo(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    return a + b + c + d;
}
```

But, compiling this (using GCC) with:

```
gcc filename.s filename.c -o filename.out
```

produces the following message:

*filename.s: Assembler messages:*

*filename.s:21: Error: too many positional arguments*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct syntax is:

```
.macro INVOKE func, argList:vararg
    .irp arg, \argList
    push \arg
    .endr
    call \func
    .irp arg, \argList
    add esp, 4
    .endr
.endm
```

Note that arguments should be reversed for `push` though. Also, ideally you'd emit a single `add esp` only.

PS: this isn't `stdcall`, it's `cdecl`.

Comment: Yup, it worked.

And yes, to make it stdcall, I removed `cleanup` and added __attribute__((stdcall)) to foo. Emiting a single `add esp` solved itself. Now just to reverse arguments...